# Reusing same widget at multiple places without rebuilding them

Tags: flutter, dart

**Note - Don't misunderstand rebuilding here with the rebuilding on setstate. I mean that using the single widget already build at one place to be used at several places instead of rebuilding it again at those places.**

Here I want to reuse the same widget in multiple places at the same time instead of rebuilding it, again and again, many times which will be expensive if the widget is complex.

I know flutter says rebuilding a widget many times should be fine but in my case, I cannot do that as the widget is very expensive.

Sample code -

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=7ba9a0d372913a792a0a7602d6fe255a).

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final Widget customContainer = const CustomContainer();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Grid"),
      ),
      body: GridView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          childAspectRatio: 1,
          crossAxisCount: 7,
          mainAxisExtent: 40,
          crossAxisSpacing: 5,
          mainAxisSpacing: 5,
        ),
        children: List.generate(42, (index) {
          return customContainer;
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomContainer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.pink,
      height: 40,
      width: 40,
    );
  }
}
```

The task is basically to bring the customContainer in the code to only build 1 time instead of 42 times for the GridView.

[image: Dev Tools]

If that can be achieved please provide an example extending the above DartPad.

And if that can never be achieved then I'm more than happy to learn why it can't be achieved.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure defining the List.generate into a variable above the build section to create it ahead of time would work. I'd also use GridView.builder for what youre trying to accomplish.

I also found this example online for you to check out that walks you through what youre attempting...
https://www.kindacode.com/article/flutter-gridview-builder-example/

Comment: Thanks but no that would still be equivalent to rebuilding elements the item count times. Which will take time a lot of time if the single item is expensive. You can yourself see that in the dev tools.